# Issue with Java Setup for Eclipse in MAC OS

Tags: java, eclipse, macos

I have already installed Java on my MAC OS its Java 9.0.4 as seen in System Preferences

I am unable to open eclipse due to error

> The eclipse executable was unable to locate its companion shared library

Earlier I had downloaded the eclipse and have copied contents to application folder and am trying to open eclipse

Comment: What version of Ecipse? You should use Oxygen.2 (4.7.2) with Java 9. You must also have the Java 9 JDK installed, the JRE won't work.

Comment: i need to work on eclipse jee version

Comment: There is a JEE release for every version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with Eclipse Installer , It automatically sets up every thing